# How do I pass a string parameter greater than varchar(8000) in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters

You get a compilation error if you define the string parameter to have a size greater than 8000

e.g.

```
The size (9000) given to the type 'varchar' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to store it as TEXT instead of varchar for string larger than 8000 in sql 2000

Answer (score 3):

> > You can't use text as a parameter value for a stored proc in SQL 2000<<
> >     Sure you can.

What you cannot do is define a local variable as text

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in SQL 2000, use the "text" data type instead.

[Choose SQL 2000 Data Types](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/General/choose_data_type.htm)

Answer (score -1):

You can't use text as a parameter value for a stored proc in SQL 2000, so usually the technique is to break up the information into chunks of 8000 characters or less and reassemble in the proc.