# How to store a string var greater than varchar(max)? 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, max, varchar, string-concatenation

I'm trying to do this:

```
DECLARE @myVar VARCHAR(MAX)
Loop with cursor
select @myVar = @myVar + bla bla bla
end loop
```

When the loop ends, @myVar is incomplete, containing only 8000 characters.

I have tryed to use text, but is not allowed to local vars.

What would be a good solution to this case?

xml var?

I have just looked this posts:

[How do I pass a string parameter greater than varchar(8000) in SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284610/how-do-i-pass-a-string-parameter-greater-than-varchar8000-in-sql-server-2000)

[Check if concatenating to a varchar(max) will go beyond max allowable characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975165/check-if-concatenating-to-a-varcharmax-will-go-beyond-max-allowable-characters)

And others through the web.

Regards.

Comment: Greater than `varchar(max)` ?? That's 2 GB of data - 2 billion characters - that's more than **200 times** the size of the entire *War and Peace* novel by Leo Tolstoj.... and that's **not big enough for you?!?**

Comment: @marc_s: The question seems to be asking why the poster's variable only contains 8000 characters at the end of the loop; I think the title is misleading. Perhaps the poster can edit to clarify what exactly is being asked here.

Comment: @KenWhite: see my response for how to fix this problem.

Comment: How are you testing the length?

Comment: Hey man, I was thinking that 8000 was the max. I'm sorry.

Comment: IIRC, 8000 bytes is the (default?) limit for retrievals in Query Manager, but it's certainly not the limit for the datatype.

Comment: @marc_s: Saw it, and upvoted. I was just trying to clarify what the poster was actually asking (and trying to get them to edit the question to do so).

Comment: DaveE I think that is it man! I was not seeing the total amount of text in query result when I was printing @myVar variable.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Seriously - `VARCHAR(MAX)` can store up to 2 GB of data - not just 8000 characters.....

Try this:

```
DECLARE @myVar VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @ix INT = 1

WHILE @ix < 1000
BEGIN
    set @myVar = @myVar + CAST('bla bla bla' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    SET @ix = @ix + 1
END

SELECT DATALENGTH(@myvar)
```

This will return a value **higher** than 8000 characters after 1000 iterations.

The point is: if you're using `varchar(max)`, you need to make sure to always **cast** all your strings to `varchar(max)` explicitly - as I did in this example. Otherwise, SQL Server will fall back to "regular" `varchar` processing, and that's indeed limited to 8000 characters....

Comment: This works fine for me without the explicit cast. Where you have to be careful is when using built-ins like REPLICATE.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: ahhh.... interesting - yes - it does seem to work just fine - even without the cast ....hmm....

Comment: I think the problem was I was printing @myVar and I was not seeing all of the chars. That is it normal?

Comment: @Murphy: the UI tools like SQL Server Mgmt Studio have a limit on how much they show - yes, that's normal.

Comment: Doesn't Varchar(max) allocate too many locations in the RAM? I mean, nvarchar allocates as much as it needs, unlike the varchar, which may not be efficient.

Comment: @Samer_Azar: varchar(max) **also** allocates just as much memory as it needs

Comment: I tried this solution and it stopped at 43680 characters. Is it possible to store more?

Comment: @A.Rashad: `varchar(max)` stores **up to 2 GB** (or **2 billion**) characters. But the Management Studio is known to have certain limitations well below that limit - it really depends on *how* you tried to insert that data.....

Comment: @marc_s Hi, Is there any way I can see the whole data from management studio?