# How to properly access a VARCHAR(MAX) parameter value of a FireDAC dataset when getting "data too large for variable" error?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe8, firedac

Our application updates and accesses data using SQL Server 2014.

I have a table of which the last column ('Contents') is created as `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

We are using Delphi XE8, and are using a FireDAC `TFDQuery` component to update this column.

```
.....
FDquery.ParamByName('Contents').AsString:=Contents;
FDquery.ExecSQL;
```

When running this update, I get the following error:

> Exception raised with message [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC]-345. Data too large for variable [CONTENTS]. Max len = [8002], actual len = [13829] Hint: set the TFDParam.Size to a greater value.

'Contents' can be string of varying length.

Browsing the web, the only reasonably simple solution that I found is changing the query as follows:

```
 FDquery.ParamByName('Contents').AsWideMemo:=Contents;
 FDquery.ExecSQL;
```

Is this acceptable, or should I be handling this differently?

There is nothing fancy with 'Contents', as I mentioned, it is simply a long string.

Comment: Possible solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097670/how-to-store-a-string-var-greater-than-varcharmax

Comment: As far as I understand it, it's a FireDAC issue ...

Comment: It's not an issue. Accessing value by `AsString` you claim that the parameter is of data type `ftString` or `ftWideString` and values are send to the DBMS accordingly. And because `ft(Wide)String` is for SQL server mapped to data types that can be at most 8k chars long, you receive such error. If you access that parameter by `As(Wide)Memo`, it is handled as `ftMemo` field. The whole point is that `As<>` access modifies parameter `DataType` and the value is send by that to DBMS.

Answer (score 3):

### Is it acceptable to access a VARCHAR(MAX) type field parameter value by the AsWideMemo property?

Not especially. For [**VARCHAR(MAX)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) field parameter use [**AsMemo**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParam.AsMemo) access. It is because you could be sending to your DBMS Unicode values to a non Unicode field. From [**the reference**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unicode_Support_(FireDAC)#Parameter_Values):

> The Unicode encoded parameter value is converted to a Unicode
>   character set, which is supported by the DBMS, and sent to the DBMS.
>   This does not depend on a client character set or on a Delphi version.

If your field would be [**NVARCHAR(MAX)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql), using [**AsWideMemo**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParam.AsWideMemo) access to the parameter value would be the right choice.

---

### Why am I getting “data too large for variable” error when having assigned a more than 8k chars long string by the AsString property?

Some background to why this happens. By accessing a certain parameter value by [**As<T>**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParam_Properties) property, the engine also sets the parameter [**DataType**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParam.DataType), if you don't explicitly do that before. In this particular case you hinted the engine that it's fine for you if it sets the parameter data type to [**ftWideString**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TFieldType) or [**ftString**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TFieldType) just by accessing parameter value by the [**AsString**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParam.AsString) property.

And thanks to data type mapping such parameter is treated as the [**VARCHAR[n]**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) or [**NVARCHAR[n]**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql) data type including its limits (hence you got a string length limit error here).

Similar, just more specific data type hint is used when you access the parameter value by [**AsMemo**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParam.AsMemo) property, it defaults to [**ftMemo**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TFieldType) data type which maps to [**VARCHAR(MAX)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql). And as you may predict,
 [**AsWideMemo**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParam.AsWideMemo) access defaults to [**ftWideMemo**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TFieldType) which maps to [**NVARCHAR(MAX)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql) data type. If you don't want to explicitly set the parameter data types but use this hinting, consult the manual to see how each used access property sets the default parameter data type.