# Firebird equivalent to start and end of the day

Tags: delphi, firebird

I need to exchange **current_date** in Firebird stored proc to Delphi equivalent of StartOfTheDay and EndOfTheDay.

Delphi's StartOfTheDay returns 18.08.2017:00.00.00.001, EndOfTheDay returns 18.08.2017:23.59.59.999.

How to do it in Firebird ?

Comment: if You read tutorial for example cron-class library, never made assumption exactly time to do something

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.DateUtils.StartOfTheDay - Returns a TDateTime that represents 12:00:00:00 A.M. on the day identified by a specified TDateTime. StartOfTheDay returns the first expressible moment of the same day as the TDateTime specified by AValue. That is, it replaces the time portion of AValue with 0 and returns the result. Your description of funtion in Delphi is incorect.

Answer (score 4):

### How to get start of the day from a DATE input?

You can write a command like this:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 1, CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS TIMESTAMP)) FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

In procedure it can be:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE DayStart TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  DayStart = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 1, CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS TIMESTAMP));
  ...
END
```

It casts [**DATE**](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-date) value to [**TIMESTAMP**](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-timestamp) (because the [**DATEADD**](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-funcs-tbl-dateadd) function is sensitive for the input data type) and then adds 1 millisecond to that value. For today you should get this (but I don't think it will match to that Delphi function result):

```
18.08.2017, 00:00:00.001
```

### How to get end of the day from a DATE input?

Similarly to the start of the day, you can write this command to get end of the day:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, CAST(CURRENT_DATE + 1 AS TIMESTAMP)) FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

In procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE DayEnd TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  DayEnd = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, CAST(CURRENT_DATE + 1 AS TIMESTAMP));
  ...
END
```

This one adds 1 day to the given [**DATE**](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-date), then casts to the [**TIMESTAMP**](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-timestamp) and subtracts 1 millisecond from it. For today it should return this (which matches the mentioned Delphi function):

```
18.08.2017, 23:59:59.999
```

### How to get DATE from a TIMESTAMP input?

If your input is of [**TIMESTAMP**](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-timestamp) type with a time portion specified, then first cast to a [**DATE**](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-date) to get rid of the [**TIME**](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-time) portion. For example to get day start from a [**TIMESTAMP**](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-timestamp) value:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 1, CAST(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AS TIMESTAMP)) FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Or similarly in a stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
AS 
DECLARE VARIABLE DayEnd TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE VARIABLE DayStart TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE VARIABLE DateTime TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  DateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; -- this has time portion if not executed at midnight
  DayStart = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 1, CAST(CAST(DateTime AS DATE) AS TIMESTAMP));
  DayEnd = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, CAST(CAST(DateTime AS DATE) + 1 AS TIMESTAMP));
  ...
END
```

Comment: Why _Bold_ font?

Comment: @Sami, I like it :) I'm using it for every link ([not only here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44579115/8041231)).

Comment: No, It's not about the links :)

Comment: @Sami, it's heading (Ctrl + H). I wanted to separate start of the day and end of the day whilst explaining a bit that chaotic SQL command.

Comment: I'd sooner use code formatting than bold for keywords like `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE`.

Comment: @Sami Quote blocks are for quotes from external sources (or the question or other questions/answers), not for emphasis or anything else. The use of headings like Victoria did is correct.

Answer (score 2):

First, note Delphi implements the StartOfTheDay function as:

```
function StartOfTheDay(const AValue: TDateTime): TDateTime;
begin
  Result := Trunc(AValue);
end;
```

This means it does not return 18.08.2017:00.00.00.001 but 18.08.201700.00.00.000, witch is true.

---

In Firebird 3.0 and up, you can implement StartOfTheDay and EndOfTheDay routines as functions:

```
create or alter function STARTOFTHEDAY (
    STAMP timestamp)
returns timestamp
as
begin
  return cast(STAMP as date);
end
```

and

```
create or alter function ENDOFTHEDAY (
    STAMP timestamp)
returns timestamp
as
begin
  return dateadd(millisecond, -1, cast(cast(STAMP as date) + 1 as timestamp));
end
```

In older versions, embed the same code in stored procedures.

Testing and usage:

```
select
  -- Date type
  STARTOFTHEDAY(current_date),
  ENDOFTHEDAY(current_date),
  -- Timestamp type
  STARTOFTHEDAY(current_timestamp),
  ENDOFTHEDAY(current_timestamp)
from RDB$DATABASE
```

Today's results:

```
STARTOFTHEDAY: 22.09.2017 00:00:00.000
ENDOFTHEDAY:   22.09.2017 23:59:59.999
```