# Getting data from SQL Database to R

Tags: sql, r, odbc, rodbc

I see a weird error while extracting data from SQL to R. Only of the columns in SQL dataset has 40,000 character (nvarchar(MAX)) .

But when I extract this data to R using `odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};_____"))`, I only 255 characters.

Howeverwhen I extract this data to R using `odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver={SQL Server};_____"))`, I get all 40,000 characters.

Not sure why this is happening. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this change to your SQL query help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12097781/18309711

Comment: Unfortunately No :(

Comment: You say "40,000 character" and `nvarchar(max)` together as if they are equivalent. They are not. Am I misinterpreting?